# jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I was wondering if you could help me with some animation in jQuery.

I have a full screen background that changes every five seconds, using animate to fade out the old one and fade in the new one. I also have a menu bar that can be hidden and revealed by clicking an open/close button. Now the problem is that when the background is changing the menu animation is really slow and jerky.

What would be the best way to run them at the same time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide some code in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front-end development is completely at the whim of the client machine.  On some it may run smooth, on others it will be horribly choppy (even if not running at the same time).  The idea behind this, since you cannot do traditional multi-threading in JavaScript, so your best choice is to either queue the animation one after the other or try to merge the two animations into one (which would work if they are both fade animations, but I think your menu bar is probably a scrolling/positioning animation).

Comment: I removed the fade on the background image so now it just swaps from image to image and its working fine now. Maybe later i will try get it working. Thanks for the advice.